# Possible "algebraic" direction in hyperplane arrangements

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, hyperplane-arrangements

I have been studying hyperplane arrangements from R. Stanley's notes and so far, I have read until lecture 5. But, Lecture 6 and end of Lecture 5 seems very combinatorial. I'm more interested in the "algebraic" direction. More specifically, in representation-theoretic perspective (if there exists any).

So, I was wondering if someone can suggest me some reference for more "algebraic" perspective of hyperplane arrangements. (It's OK if it's not representation-theoretic)

Comment: Orlik and Terao's Arrangements of Hyperplanes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I recall correctly, Stanley does not discuss the so-called "Tits monoid" associated to a hyperplane arrangement. The relationship between the Tits monoid and the lattice of flats of a hyperplane arrangement is the main focus of the book "Topics in hyperplane arrangements" by Aguiar and Mahajan (it's free online at [http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~maguiar/surv-226.pdf](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Emaguiar/surv-226.pdf)). Actually, they have another more recent book on hyperplane arrangements as well - I'm not quite sure the difference between the two. Anyways, this is definitely an "algebraic" direction in hyperplane arrangement theory.

The study of free arrangements/the module of logarithmic derivations -- as championed by Terao -- is another completely different algebraic (or more specifically, algebro-geometric) direction in hypreplane arrangement theory. This one is arguably more connected (at least "morally") to the stuff in Stanley's notes (e.g. I believe Stanley mentions free arrangements, at least in an exercise). This is discussed e.g. in the book by Orlik and Terao mentioned in the comment above.

Comment: By the way, a perhaps superficial distinction between these two directions: first one concerns arrangements over $\mathbb{R}$, second one concerns arrangements over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: The Tits monoid essentially views a hyperplane arrangement as an oriented matroid.  An oriented matroid is defined as a monoid of covectors with some extra properties.  I don't know if there is any reasonable algebraic way to detect if an oriented matroid is realizable from a hyperplane arrangement.  These monoids come up in our monogragph https://www.ams.org/books/memo/1345/memo1345.pdf (and there is a semigroup for affine arrangements).

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: your link requires a sign-in. But I believe the book in question is "Cell complexes, poset topology and the representation theory of algebras arising in algebraic combinatorics and discrete geometry" by Margolis, Saliola, and Steinberg (https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=4365944).